# What is wrong with this java for loop condition?

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors

1.

```
for (int i = 0; (boolean)true; i++) { 

}
```

2.

```
for (int i = 0; (boolean)false; i++) {

}
```

3.

```
boolean t=false;
for (int i = 0; t; i++) {

}
```

The first for loop *compiles* & *runs*, but the second for loop `compilation fails with error`.  It says `Unreachable Statement`. And the third for loop *compiles* & *runs*.

Comment: Now if you add `final` in front of `boolean t=false;` it won't compile again. It's all about what compiler can guarantee.

Answer (score 4):

The first loop is infinite loop. Since the condition is **always true**, and will always be satisfied.

It's like writing:

```
int i=0;
while(true)
   i++;
```

As you can see, the condition is always `true` and nothing changes this true.

The second loop is `Unreachable code` since the piece of code below this loop will never be reached (`false` is always false and you never change it). So it's redundant.

**See Chapter 14.21. [Unreachable Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)**

Since `Java` knows that the programmer is human :) it notifies you about this to prevent mistakes.

Note that `while(false)` or the second loop you have differ from `if(false)...` since `while(false)` (or the loop you have) doesn't make sense because the code below it **will no be execute**. Not like `if(false)` that might have `else`, so the compiler doesn't complain about it in this case.

---

*Regarding the OP update:*

In the third case there will be no compilation error since the `false` value is assigned to the variable and in this case, the variable can be re-assigned to have `true` value in it. So the compiler doesn't arise an error.
Note that if the variable is declared as `final` then the compiler will arise an error since this variable can be never assigned to a new value, thus the code below the `for` loop will be *unreachable*.

Comment: +1 For the update (I was about to added). One simple could it be a double loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the second `for` loop, the condition is always `false` so the `for` block (even if is empty) will never be executed (it is `unreacheable`).

Like in this case :

```
if (false) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; <This_has_to_be_true>; i++)
```

The second part of the for loop has to be true for the loop to execute. Since you're manually setting it to be always fase, the loop will never run, hence the code inside it is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you the code inside the second loop (even if empty) will *never* be reached and executed, because the condition is always `false`.

BTW, why are you trying to do this anyway?